# how can i get reaction time in python?

Tags: python, keyboard, response, real-time

I am unable to get the right time of reaction.

Following is my attempt on achieving it:

```
kb = keyboard.Keyboard()
RT = core.Clock()

def run(data):
    trial=0 
    for j in range(1,5):
        for i in data:
            kb.clock.reset()
            excelTrialEq = trial
            print (i)
            myword.text=i[0]
            myword.draw()
            mywin.flip() #draw letter 

            RT.reset()           
            RT.add((0.25) + i[1]
            core.wait(0.25)
            mywin.flip() #draw blank(ISI)

            while RT.getTime() < 0 : pass # wait till end stimulus showing + ISI
```

i expect the output like

```
['M', 1]
1 2 M 1
space, 0.50980908090
...
```

but the actual output is

```
['M', 1]
1 2 M 1
['K', 1]
space -0.25774913992427173
...
```

Comment: I think the [timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html) is for your needs

Comment: i didn't see any platform information. Bash, CMD, WIN, LIN, TK,TCL etc.!

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear from your code what you want to do. However, if I understand correctly you show something on the screen and wait for the user to press the spacebar. 
The most simple thing to do would be this:

```
import time

#When the item appears on the screen
startTime = time.time()

#When the user presses space
endTime = time.time()

reactionTime = endTime - startTime
```

Comment: this is what i want! but I don't know how to apply this to my script exactly. i show some letter on the screen and wait for the user to press the space bar. but after a certain time, the trial ends and the next trial appears.